# Hook pages by id on static front-page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to build a one page website upon the Wordpress CMS. I'm looking for a way too hook my pages on a static frontpage by id, since I have several page types.

I've tried:

```
$id=6; 
$post = get_post($id); 
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
echo $content;
```

But this returns only the content and not the content with the HTML. Any tips on how to achieve this? or other ways to build a one-page website upon Wordpress?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you paste in some example content that your code is echoing with `echo $content;`?

Answer (score 0):

To output the HTML properly, try using PHP's HTML entity encoding/decoding related functions to convert entities back to their applicable characters (e.g. `<` and `>`).

WordPress has an internal function called `wpautop` that converts double linefeeds (`\n`) into paragraph splits. `wp_texturize` (or something similarly named) converts some characters to proper variants, such as quote marks and similar.

Try this:

```
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', wpautop( wp_texturize( html_entity_decode( $post -> post_content ) ) ) );

// Note: not properly tested, but should probably output properly "HTMLized" contents.
```

If you want to output something else than the HTML tags that are inside the post contents (and inserted using the post editor in wp-admin), you'll have to work with the theme templates.

EDIT:

To insert whole templates into the homepage to create a single-page website, you'll need to create each "page" as a template file. Assuming you have `front-page.php`, `content-about.php`, `content-portfolio.php` and so on. Additionally you most probably have `header.php` and `footer.php`.

In simplified form, each of the content templates that would be inserted to `front-end.php` could look something like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * content-about.php
 */

// Get the wanted content as WP Post.
$page_obj = get_page_by_title( 'About' );
$page_content = wpautop( $page_obj -> post_content );

?>

<article id="about"> <!-- Begin a new section for the one-page template. -->
    <h2><?php echo $page_obj -> post_title; ?></h2>
    <?php echo $page_content; ?>
</article>
```

Additional templates (`content-portfolio.php`, `content-contact.php` and so on) should follow a similar structure.

Then in `front-page.php` you need to include your `header.php` and `footer.php` as you normally would. Then inbetween use `get_template_part` calls to fetch and display the `content-abc.php` templates within `front-page.php`:

```
<?php

/**
 * front-page.php
 */

get_header(); ?>

<!-- Add some markup if you want to. -->

<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'about' ); // 'content-about.php' ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'portfolio' ); // 'content-portfolio.php' ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'awesometemplate' ); // 'awesometemplate.php' ?>

<!-- Add some markup if you want to. -->

<?php get_footer();
```

Now after WordPress and PHP parse the `front-page.php` template, the resulting output might look like this (depending on what you insert into each included template):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
...
</head>

<body>

    <!-- header.php visible contents here -->

    <!-- content-about.php: -->
    <article id="about">
        <h2>About</h2>
        <p>Well hello there! This is some <em>nice</em> content from content-about.php.</p>
    </article>

    <!-- content-portfolio.php: -->
    <article id="portfolio">
        <h2>Portfolio</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
            ...
            </li>
        </ul>
    </article>

    <!-- awesometemplate.php: -->
    <article id="awesome">
        <h2>Awesome!</h2>
        <table>
        ...
        </table>
    </article>

    <!-- footer.php visible contents here -->

</body>

</html>
```

Now you've got separated templates that hold content and are embedded into `front-page.php` to create a single-page master template. The it's up to you to use CSS and JS to make it flashy if you want to.

Note: you can also use PHP's very own `include` or `require` functions to insert the sub-templates to `front-page.php`.

Comment: what do you mean by work with theme templates? i think that is what i need since i developed all the templates but i need a way to put them al in one page..

Comment: Do you mean you want to "embed" the WP `single.php` template into the static homepage?

Comment: No, i'm making a single page wordpress website. for each section i have a different template since they have different layouts. So for example, i have a homepage.php, a textpage.php and a portfolio.php. I want to inlude the created pages in front-page.php so that they show as a singlepage website

Comment: So in essence you would just be using simple PHP `include`s to insert the wanted templates inside `front-page.php`. WordPress has a function called `get_template_part` which might be useful.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how I would go about including various other templates to a central homepage template.

Comment: Thank you very much, i gave this a try as soon as i'm home

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to construct a custom query. You can use the Post and Page parameters to call your pages you need to display on your front page.

Inside the loop you'll have the ability to directly work with the template tags like `the_content`. You can also load template tags and HTML structures conditionally inside the loop on a per page basis with the use of `is_page()` or `is_page_template()`

Here is an example from the codec. Modify to suite your needs

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'post__not_in' => array( 2, 5, 12, 14, 20 ) ) );

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
$the_query->the_post();
   the_content();
}
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```